# Is it possible to reach King vs King by moving each piece at most twice?

Tags: theory, problems, records, mathematics, kings

I'm interested in short games that reach a King vs King endgame. Sam Lloyd reached King vs King after only 17 moves. This has since been improved to 16.5 moves. (See [this](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/18258/fastest-king-vs-king-endgame) and [that](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/23863/is-this-the-quickest-way-to-clearing-the-board-to-two-kings).) One can show that this is optimal. In these games, almost all captures are performed by queens and rooks, but I'd like to see a massacre with more diverse captures.

**Question 1:** Is it possible to reach a King vs King endgame by moving each piece at most twice?

Notice that you can't get away with moving each piece at most once, since this would give King vs King in only 16 moves.

**Question 2:** Assuming such games exist, what's the shortest game?

Please post a game and report the number of moves.

Answer (score 10):

**Answer 1**: Yes, this is possible.  Here is an example game in 27 moves:

```
[FEN ""]

1. a4 a5 2. b4 b5 3. bxa5 bxa4 4. Rxa4 Nc6 5. g4 Nxa5 6. Rxa5 Rxa5 7. h4 g5 8. hxg5 h5 9. gxh5 d5 10. c4 Nf6 11. cxd5 Nxd5 12. e4 Bb7 13. exd5 Bxd5 14. Nc3 e6 15. Nxd5 exd5 16. Bg2 c5 17. Bxd5 Rxh5 18. d4 Rxg5 19. dxc5 Bxc5 20. f4 Bxg1 21. Rxg1 f6 22. fxg5 fxg5 23. Rxg5 Qxd5 24. Ke2 Qxd1+ 25. Kxd1 Rxg5 26. Bxg5 Kd7 27. Bd8 Kxd8
```

You can even insert some moves that slow the game down so that *every piece moves **exactly** twice*.  Sadly, this is the opposite of your second question.

```
[FEN ""]

1. a3 a6 2. a4 a5 3. b4 b5 4. bxa5 bxa4 5. Rxa4 Nc6 6. g4 Nxa5 7. Rxa5 Rxa5 8. h4 g6 9. Nh3 g5 10. hxg5 h6 11. Ng1 h5 12. gxh5 d6 13. c4 d5 14. Qc2 Nf6 15. cxd5 Nxd5 16. e4 Bb7 17. exd5 Bxd5 18. Nc3 e6 19. Nxd5 exd5 20. Bg2 c6 21. Qd1 c5 22. Bxd5 Rxh5 23. d4 Rxg5 24. dxc5 Bxc5 25. f4 Bxg1 26. Rxg1 f6 27. fxg5 fxg5 28. Rxg5 Qxd5 29. Ke2 Qxd1+ 30. Kxd1 Rxg5 31. Bxg5 Kd7 32. Bd8 Kxd8
```